# Powershell - $var.ToString(x,y) issue

Tags: powershell

for a user creation scrip in powershell i'm using textbox object to fill the information of the new user (family name, first name)

I return a value like that:

```
$TextlabelUsername.text = $Textbox1.text.ToString().Substring(0,5)
```

Which apply on a button click.

But using that methode if one of my string value is less then 5 caracters the script return an error that the string is not enough long.

Is there a way to select 5 or less caracters or an other method to process ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = $Textbox1.text.ToString()
$TextlabelUsername.text = $str.Substring(0, [math]::Min(5, $str.Length))
```

Comment: I wish I could be such smart with programming thanks for the hand on this.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with Ansgar Wiecher's method. Here is an alternative though:

```
$TextLabelUserName.Text = $Textbox1.Text.ToString() -replace '(.{0,5}).*', '$1'
```